# Spring Boot Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to consume this [web-service](http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL) but I'm getting `SoapExeption`.

Below is my method for sending the request. How can I fix this issue in Spring boot?

```
public class CalcClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CalcClient.class);
    private ObjectFactory objectFactory;

    @Autowired
    public void setObjectFactory(ObjectFactory objectFactory) {
        this.objectFactory = objectFactory;
    }

    public JAXBElement<AddResponse> sendAndReceive() {
        Add request = objectFactory.createAdd();
        request.setIntA(12);
        request.setIntB(12);
        LOGGER.info("Sending request");
        JAXBElement<AddResponse> response = (JAXBElement<AddResponse>) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive("http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx", request);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue accessing this service, You'll get an error for trying to bind `AddResponse` to `JAXBElement`. You need to set your `soapAction` in your code, like below using `WebServiceMessageCallback`

```
public AddResponse sendAndReceive() {
    Add request = objectFactory.createAdd();
    request.setIntA(12);
    request.setIntB(12);
    LOGGER.info("Sending request");
    AddResponse response = (AddResponse) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive("http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx", request, new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
        @Override
        public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage webServiceMessage) throws IOException, TransformerException {
            ((SoapMessage)webServiceMessage).setSoapAction("http://tempuri.org/Add");
        }
    });
    return response;
}
```